# Problem in truncating c array

Tags: c, arrays

I declared an array and take input from user. Now i want to check duplicate entries, they have to be deleted and memory should be freed. Is it possible to free memory.

freeing the unused memory and reducing the array size?

I entered `[10,21,3,4,4,2,6,7,21,4,10]`.it should get truncated as `[10,21,3,4,2,6,7]`  and array length should now be 7,and i don't want to use sorting.

Comment: Is this a truncation problem or a duplication problem? Make up your mind.

Comment: It is indeed possible to free memory. Can we see some code of what you're trying? Is this perhaps your homework?

Comment: If you have already declared array the array then removing duplicate value will not reduce size or free any memory as you are just deleting the value in the memory space not the memory area..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I declared an array of length 100 and took input from user**

so you mean like this:

```
    int input[100];
/* - ask 100 input from user */
```

**Is it possible to free memory**

the answer is no because you statically allocate 100 integers.

If you want to be able to reduce memory then you should do something like this:

```
int *tempBuffer=malloc(100*sizeof(int)); /* dynamic allocation */

for(i=0;i<100;++i) scanf("%d",&tempBuffer[i]);/* - ask 100 input from user */

int uniqueN=10   /* - assume the first 10 entries are the unique entries */

int *realBuffer=malloc(uniqueN*sizeof(int)); /* - allocate new buffer just enough for the unique entries */

for(i=0;i<uniqueN;++i) realBuffer[i]=tempBuffer[i];  /* - copy the unique entries from input to the final buffer */

free(tempBuffer);  /* - tempBuffer is now unused, free it */

/* here we have realBuffer with just enough size, no unused memory */
```

Another solution is to `realloc` `tempBuffer` after arranging the first `uniqueN` entries to be the unique entries:

```
realloc(tempBuffer,uniqueN);
```

don't forget to check if `malloc` or `realloc` returns `NULL`

Comment: if user entered 21 values,my program truncated and now there are 11 values left,now how to use free() ,it is not happening ,i need to free from position 10 th to 99

Comment: (see my edited answer) 1st: you must use dynamic allocation malloc/realloc/calloc to be able to 'free' it later. 2nd: array is statically allocated so you cannot free it just because you don't need to. 3rd: If you request 100 integer from malloc, you can only free all of it, you cannot choose to free position 10th to 99. The solution for your problem is copying the 10unique entries to another table (this table is created by another malloc(10*sizeof(int)) or using realloc after making sure that the all of the first entries is unique.

Answer (score 4):

In C, you cannot change the size of an array. If you use dynamically allocated memory (with `malloc()`), you can use `realloc()` to resize the memory region, or allocate a new region, copy the data into it and free the old one.

A solution that is often acceptable is to simply leave part of the array unused. This is done by recording how many entries are used in a separate integer variable.

Comment: problem with realloc is it is not allocating from position 0th

Comment: @Abhishek `realloc()` doesn't return the same memory location as the original allocation (if I understand your statement correctly). There is also no guarantee that it will work so you must check the return value appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Simple implementation:

1. When you do find a duplicate entry, shuffle the array left to fill the gap (covering the duplicate).
2. Use `realloc` to reduce your allocation.

Note that you simply can't delete an arbitrary memory location. If runtime for filling gaps is a problem, consider an alternate structure such as a linked list, which would allow removal from the middle.

Removing duplicate entries is another problem. The general case involves sorting. You may have a special case which allows for better behavior.

Comment: Of course, that depends on whether the array was allocated statically or dynamically.  Static arrays cannot be resized.

Comment: then the unused memory location contains garbage,i wanted to free those memory location,thanks man i will try to work with realloc

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not dynamic in C. That said, you can access entries beyond the last one (given that an array variable is essentially a pointer). However, this is not safe.

Also, you cannot delete "array entries". You can move the rest of the elements to occupy the respectively previous positions. However, you cannot actually delete the area occupied by the element since an array is a contiguous piece of memory.